# Can't edit a projects VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been given a project called FTP which I am required to test, to a degree. The problem I've come across is that I can't edit any of the code in this project (You may be wondering why I am editing code to test - this isn't a formal test phase by any means, more of a try this, `Debug.print` that to test a value etc.)

Let me explain abit more about this project - this project fits into other projects to act as a method for FTP, hence the name - my job was to test it to ensure it works as expected.

So, I'm trying to edit the code but can't. I've checked the following:

- The project isn't locked or in read-only mode. I right-clicked on the project and selected `Properties` and selected `Protection.` The `Lock project for viewing` box is **not** checked.
- As a test i added a `MsgBox` dialog to check a variable value and tried to save it but the save icon can't be clicked.
- I opened the database by holding the Shift key to bypass all the usual stuff.

So, again, why can't I edit this code?

Comment: It sounds like the database is being opened read-only. Are you opening it from a shared location?

Comment: That's what i was thinking. No it exists on my local machine but does have functionality in it that allows it to connect to servers - don't think that would stop it though.

Comment: Is the situation that you can *view* module code but not make changes?

Comment: correct - view but cant save any edits

Comment: Can you create a new db file, open it, and import the modules from the original db?

Comment: Hi Hans - yes I did but the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention which version of Access you are using but here are a few things to check:

- Make sure that your have the rights to the folder where the files are located. Make sure you can read/write in that folder and that the Access file also has the same security rights.
- Make sure that the folder is added to the list of [Trusted Locations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-HA010354311.aspx) in Access (2007/2010/2013).
  This is necessary if you want to be using VBA or macros.
- Make a copy of the database as a backup, then try to do a Compact & Repair on the database. If it fails, what error message do you get?
- Open the database and see if the option "Save Database as..." is available and if you can save a copy of the database under a different name.
- Maybe the creator of the project added some code to prevent changes to the database. If that is the case, he probably added an Autoexec macro that may be calling some VBA when you open the project.
  You can press the SHIFT key when you open the database to prevent Access from auto-executing any code at startup. If someone somehow added code to prevent changes, pressing SHIFT when launching the database will prevent any code from executing.

Comment: Tried all of the above and nothing works - the code the creator has doesn't appear to have anything that would stop the edition. I'll follow this up further and post back if I find anything - thanks for the help

Comment: i really appreciate that but don't think i can risk sending the code outside of the companies network. Thanks anyway though!